# Multiple hazelcast instances with its own JVM on single host communicating with other hosts of similar setting

Tags: jvm, hazelcast

We are currently using a cluster of 4 nodes, each with a memory of 244GB. However, during garbage collection(GC) peaks, the response time increases to 7s. Our clients operate with a response time of 5s. We are hoping to reduce the GC time by using smaller heap. The question is:

1. How do we run multiple hazelcast instances on each of the nodes with each instance running on its own JVM(hence using smaller heap)?
2. How do we enable the instances on one host to discover the instances on the other hosts?

Answer (score 0):

1. Just launch the instance as usual - I'm not sure I understand the problem
2. Please read the [clustering documentation](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/#setting-up-clusters). It can be as simple just launching them, and they will automatically find each other by multicasting. Or you can explicitly configure IPs and ports:

   ```xml
   <hazelcast>
     <network>
       <join>
         <multicast enabled="false">
         <tcp-ip enabled="true">
           <member>machine1</member>
           <member>machine2</member>
           <member>machine3:5799</member>
           <member>192.168.1.0-7</member>
           <member>192.168.1.21</member>
         </tcp-ip>
       </join>
     </network>
   </hazelcast>
   ```